# Is there any way to use $exists with $expr in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am new with mongoDB and I need to used $exists with $expr in mongoDB, i tried following:

```
$lookup: {
    as: "collectionDet",
    from: "collection",
    let: { userId: "$userId" },
    pipeline: [{
        $match: {
        $expr: {
            $and: [
            { $eq: ["$_id", "$$userId"]},
            { $eq: ["$status", true], },
            {
                $or: [
                { $eq: ["$isDeleted", false ], },
                { $exists: ["$isDeleted", false ] },
                ],
            }
            ],
        },
        },
    }],
}
```

this is return error like:

> "message": "Unrecognized expression '$exists'"

Is there any way to used $exists in $expr or any other alternative available?

Comment: Can you tell how your collection looks like and what are you trying to achieve. How to use  $exists with $expr is something you should lookup in the documentation(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query)

Comment: maybe you can use `isDeleted != true` instead of `isDelete == false || isDeleted missing`

Comment: You can also pull everything but the first condition under `$and` out of the `$expr` and use them directly as filters under `$match`. Only the first one depends on an evaluated expressions, the others match against constants.