# Mongodb $exists inside $expr in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I want to add multiple conditions on join. Join those docs (of the same collection) who met the following conditions:

1. Have opposite gender
2. Have age (IF EXISTS) between the primary doc age preference and primary doc have `age` (IF EXISTS) between the foreign doc preference (i.e two-way check)

My attempt is the following but has two issues:

1. `$exists` can't be used inside `$expr` idk why
2. Age query is one way right now

```
$lookup: {
       "from": "appusers",
       "let": { 'gen': "$gender",'pref': "$preference" },
       "pipeline": [{
         $match: {$expr: {
         $and: [
             { $ne: ["$gender", "$$gen"]},
             { $or: [
              {$exists: {"$age": false}},
              {$and: [
                 { $gte: ["$age", '$$pref.age_from' ] },
                 { $lte: [ "$age", '$$pref.age_to' ] }
               ]}
             ]}
           ]
        }}}],
   
       "as": "matches"
   }
```

**Example:
Input Docs:**

```
    {
      name: "person1",
      age: 36,
      gender: "Male",
      preference: {
        age_from: 25,
        age_to: 35
      }
    }
    
    {
      name: "person2",
      age: 18,
      gender: "Female",
      preference: {
        age_from: 25,
        age_to: 40
      }
    }
    
    {
      name: "person3",
      age: 26,
      gender: "Female",
      preference: {
        age_from: 30,
        age_to: 35
      }
    }
    
    {
      name: "person4",
      age: 26,
      gender: "Female",
      preference: {
        age_from: 30,
        age_to: 40
      }
    }
```

**Output:**
For person 1 the matches array will show only person 4 (and similarly person 4 match will show person 1) i.e.:

```
  {
    name: person1,
    age: 36,
    gender: "Male",
    preference: {
      age_from: 28,
      age_to: 35
    },
    matches: [
      {
        name: person4,
        ...
      }
  
    ]
  }
```

I have viewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59068744/9399066) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51311191/9399066) but didn't help

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68255363/or-with-if-and-in-mongodb/68255564#68255564

Comment: Can we have some sample dataset and expected output ?

Comment: @ray I have added sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `$exists` problem, you can wrap `age` with `$ifNull` and use `$eq` to check for the existence.

For the 2-way age matching, I think you just need to repeat your age matching criteria from person1 to person4 for person4 to person1. Although in your current given test case, no match will be found as person4's age is out of person1's preference.

```js
db.appusers.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      name: "person1"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      "from": "appusers",
      "let": {
        "a": "$age",
        "gen": "$gender",
        "pref": "$preference"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $ne: [
                    "$$gen",
                    "$gender"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $and: [
                    {
                      $or: [
                        {
                          $eq: [
                            {
                              "$ifNull": [
                                "$age",
                                "age-not-exists"
                              ]
                            },
                            "age-not-exists"
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          $and: [
                            {
                              $gte: [
                                "$age",
                                "$$pref.age_from"
                              ]
                            },
                            {
                              $lte: [
                                "$age",
                                "$$pref.age_to"
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      $or: [
                        {
                          $eq: [
                            {
                              "$ifNull": [
                                "$$a",
                                "age-not-exists"
                              ]
                            },
                            "age-not-exists"
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          $and: [
                            {
                              $gte: [
                                "$$a",
                                "$preference.age_from"
                              ]
                            },
                            {
                              $lte: [
                                "$$a",
                                "$preference.age_to"
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "matches"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g2IraJpZNRh) for your reference.

Comment: Oh sorry! yes you're right. I updated person1 age preference now

Comment: @artsnr [This](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GQWgxAY60R4) should work with your updated person1 age preference.

Comment: It doesn't accommodate the case if preference doesn't exists....need existence check on age and preference. If both are there then compare else no comparison and include the doc

Comment: @artsnr can you update the question with your new test cases?

Answer (score 1):

> `$exists` can't be used inside `$expr` idk why

[$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) Allows the use of aggregation expressions within the query language, and [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) is not an aggregation operator,

You just need to correct the 2 things:

- put `$expr` condition inside first `$and` condition
- put `$expr` in last `$and` condition

```
db.appusers.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "appusers",
      let: { gen: "$gender", pref: "$preference" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $and: [
              { $expr: { $ne: ["$gender", "$$gen"] } },
              {
                $or: [
                  { age: { $exists: false } },
                  {
                    $expr: {
                      $and: [
                        { $gte: ["$age", "$$pref.age_from"] },
                        { $lte: ["$age", "$$pref.age_to"] }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "matches"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D-KWLAwgU-8)

Answer (score 0):

You can use $eq undefined for the field age instead of the $exists

```
{
   "from": "appusers",
   "let": { 'gen': "$gender",'pref': "$preference" },
   "pipeline": [{
     $match: {$expr: {
     $and: [
         { $ne: ["$gender", "$$gen"]},
         { $or: [
          {$eq: ["$age" , undefined]},
          {$and: [
             { $gte: ["$age", '$$pref.age_from' ] },
             { $lte: [ "$age", '$$pref.age_to' ] }
           ]}
         ]}
       ]
    }}}],

   "as": "matches"
}
```